# Wordnik authentication errors

Tags: c#, authentication

I'm attempting to retrieve an authentication token from Wordnik by using the provided API. However, I cannot seem to get it to work; I seem to be stuck getting 401 and 403 errors.

The following is the code I am using to request authentication from the API:

```
string authRequest = 
    String.Format("http://api.wordnik.com//v4/account.json/authenticate/{0}",
    this.userName);

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(authRequest) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

// When this is added, I get 403 errors
///request.Headers.Add("api_key", APIKey);

string postData = "password=" + password;
byte[] encodedData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentLength = encodedData.Length;

Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(encodedData, 0, encodedData.Length);
stream.Close();

string responseText;

using(HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(responseText);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Can any of you tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Nothing seems wrong - have you tried asking on https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/wordnik-api? It's their Google Group.

Comment: I've added a post to their group. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a double slash in the request URL:

"http://api.wordnik.com//v4"